# Delay/discrepancy between expected and actual output to iPython output

Tags: python, canopy

I'm using the Enthought Canopy IDE to write Python and the the output of `print` commands do not reach the ipython output window at the time when I would expect them to. The clearest way to explain is to give an example:

```
import time

print 1
print 2
time.sleep(1)
print 3

for i in range(10):
    print i
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

The initial `1`, `2` and `3` are displayed simultaneously after a second, and then there is a half second delay before the next `0` is displayed.

(as opposed to the expected instantaneous and simultaneous display of `1` and `2`, then a 1 second delay before a simultaneous display of `3` and `0`, then half second delays)

This is causing me issues as I am looking to get readouts of variables before a time consuming portion of script runs, and I cannot get it to display these readouts without terminating the program after calling the `print` command.

Any ideas/solutions?

I'm on Windows 7, let me know if you need any other specs/config details...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start the Python interpreter with an additional `-u` parameter, which gives you unbuffered output (i.e. instant).
Or you can call `sys.stdout.flush()` after every `print`. Maybe even wrapping it in a function like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

def print_flush(*args):
    print(*args)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Yes, the simplest is simply to call `sys.stdout.flush()` whenever you want to see everything that's been printed. This can be an issue in any program, but is even more so when, as in Canopy's Python pane, the kernel (where the print command is executing) is in a different process than the front end (where the output is displayed).